# JSF ResultSet in h:dataTable with dynamic columns

Tags: jsf, resultset

I am currently trying to display a ResultSet in a h:dataTable in JSF.

Basically what I am doing is executing a SQL statement which can be inserted on the website and I want to display the result of that in a table.
I can not create model classes because the tables that are used are also dynamic.
The tricky part is the fact, that I do not know how many columns there are in the ResultSet, nor the datatypes(currently I am getting these from the ResultSetMetaData).

How would I go about displaying something with dynamic columns and column content(different datatypes) in a table on a website using JSF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next time try printing something like this in plain java and try to 'extrapolate' to JSF/XHTML/EL/... That is exactely what the 'answer' does...

Answer (score 0):

Have a data structure like `List<Map<String, Object>> results` in your managed bean to store the results.
On UI side, use 2 nested `ui:repeat` elements instead of an `h:dataTable`.
Outer repeat will loop rows (`results`), inner repeat will loop columns (`result.keySet()`), each cell will get its value by `result.get(fieldName)`.

Not-tested UI code:

```
<table>
    <ui:repeat value="#{mb.results}" var="result"> 
        <tr>
            <ui:repeat value="#{result.keySet()}" var="fieldName">
                <td>
                    #{result.get(fieldName)}
                </td>
            </ui:repeat>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```